# In Rust, how to coerce a mutex lock into a reference with identical lifetime?

Tags: rust, mutex, smart-pointers, lifetime

Considering the following 2 functions that are very similar:

```rust
    pub fn locked_fusion_proto<'a>() -> Result<MutexGuard<'a, (Box<(dyn Fusion + 'static)>, bool)>>
    {
        let c = Self::existing().unwrap();
        let mx = c.fusion.as_ref().unwrap();
        let lock = mx.lock()?;
        Ok(lock)
    }

    pub fn locked_fusion_proto2<'a>() -> Result<&'a mut (Box<(dyn Fusion + 'static)>, bool)> {
        let c = Self::existing().unwrap();
        let mx = c.fusion.as_ref().unwrap();
        let lock = mx.lock()?;
        let lock_as_ref: &mut (Box<dyn Fusion>, bool) = &mut *mx.lock()?;
        Ok(lock_as_ref)
    }
```

the first one compiles successfully despite that lock is a local variable, the type & livetime of lock was automatically figured out by the compiler to be `'a`.

the second one fails with the following message:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
   --> src/lib.rs:243:9
    |
242 |         let lock_as_ref: &mut (Box<dyn Fusion>, bool) = &mut *mx.lock()?;
    |                                                               ---------- temporary value created here
243 |         Ok(lock_as_ref)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

this entails at least 2 problems:

- the lifetime of `lock_as_ref` is automatically inferred as `&mut`, instead of `&'a mut`.
- the reference cannot be copied to be owned to a variable outside the function, despite  that it can be easily done.

Obviously &'a mut is only a barebone reference that is not as powerful as a smart pointer, but apparent this is the only method to effectively return a reference INSIDE the tuple `(Box<(dyn Fusion + 'static)>, bool)`, e.g.:

```
    pub fn locked_fusion<'a>() -> Result<&'a mut Box<dyn Fusion>> {
        let c = Self::existing().unwrap();
        let mx = c.fusion.as_ref().unwrap();
        let lock = mx.lock()?;
        todo!()
    }
```

In this case, what's the correct way to return a reference of `Box<dyn Fusion>` with least runtime overhead?

You can find the [whole project on github](https://github.com/hpvdt/ar-drivers-rs/blob/5e45aa5fd4b58ff713a9dca7764fa395880d9f62/src/lib.rs#L230)

Comment: `locked_fusion_proto2()` cannot be written. Period.

Comment: And to clarify, `locked_fusion_proto2()` can't be written because the mutex guard is a smart pointer, you can move the guard around as long as it remains within the domain of validity of the mutex, but you can't *drop* the mutex guard and still keep a reference, the reference only exists through the guard.

Comment: yes that totally make sense & returning a barebone reference is a bad idea, but how to return 1 or many lock views in this case that can refer to the original lock?

Comment: You can't. What you can probably do, depending on your use case, is to inverse the control flow order: instead of _returning_ views into the original lock, take a closure as an argument and call this closure from `lock_fusion` with the lock references as arguments.

Comment: thanks a lot, already doing it. I just think a view should be easy and should already be implemented in an library